# SOAP requests with Python

Tags: python-3.x, soap, python-requests

I am trying to implement an automated VAT validation as provided by:
http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/technicalInformation.html

Basically, the code I wrote sends a number of requests and writes the response in excel. the problem is i cannot find why I don't get a response for what i need, or rather, the response as it should be as per example.

part of the code with the request:

```
>import reqests
>url='http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl'
>headers = {'content-type': 'text/soap+xml'}
>body= """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
>          <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
>          <soapenv:Header/>
>          <soapenv:Body>
>          <urn:checkVat  xmlns:urn="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types">
>          <urn:countryCode>NL</urn:countryCode>
>          <urn:vatNumber>800938495B01</urn:vatNumber>
>          </urn:checkVat>
>          </soapenv:Body>
>          </soapenv:Envelope>"""
> 
>r=requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
>r.status_code
>print(r.text)
```

I get as a response the very content of the page http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl
and not the respons as per example.

exapme request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
   <urn:checkVat  
xmlns:urn="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types">
   <urn:countryCode>NL</urn:countryCode>
  <urn:vatNumber>800938495B01</urn:vatNumber>
  </urn:checkVat>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

example response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <urn:checkVatResponse 
xmlns:urn="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types">
   <urn:countryCode>NL</urn:countryCode>
   <urn:vatNumber> 800938495B01</urn:vatNumber>
  <urn:requestDate>2010-06-28+02:00</urn:requestDate>
   <urn:valid>true</urn:valid>
  </urn:checkVatResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

some other valid codes to check are:

DE  147799609

SK  2023661948

CZ  26697131

I know there are some working programs on web developed in php and .net, but I wonder if I can get it working with python, as it is a part of a bigger process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to do it with suds-jurko

```
> from suds.client import Client
> url="http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl"
> client = Client(url)
> print(client) # to check the methonds
> r=client.service.checkVat('NL', '800938495B01')
> print(r)
```

It is not exactly as per example, but it returns the needed data.

Comment: I'm stuck on similar. I'm trying to use request instead of suds or other.

Comment: i need to do the soap call to an API, but what is this wsdl url?